# Are Native Express Ads Deprecated?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, native-ads

I tried implementing **Native Express Ads**, but for testing purposes i can't find the test ad id.

I found alot of posts which just used the test id for banner ads `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`and for some reason this does work.

Now my question is if **Native Express Ads** are still recommended to use as an ad type or are they deprecated and should i switch to **Native Advanced Ads**?

**My code**

```
LinearLayout adContainer  = findViewById(R.id.adContainer);
mAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(getApplicationContext());
mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(320,50);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
adContainer.addView(mAdView);

LinearLayout adContainer2  = findViewById(R.id.adContainer2);
mAdView2 = new NativeExpressAdView(getApplicationContext());
mAdView2.setAdSize(new AdSize(320,50);
mAdView2.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
adContainer2.addView(mAdView2);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("4EF772AE9549741BE0E1FCA236C7382C").build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
mAdView2.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right now google has replaced Native Express Ads with Native Advanced Ads.
Here is the official link of Google Admob documentation

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced